# SQL Server 2012 group columns into one

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `HL_A` which maps to `HL_B` in one-to-many relationship (`HL_A.ID = HL_B.ID`). Then `HL_B` maps to `HL_C` in one-to-one (`HL_B.ValudID = HL_C.ID`) relationship.

Example as shown below:

```
HL_A
╔════╤═════════════╗
║ ID │ ProductType ║
╠════╪═════════════╣
║ 1  │             ║
╚════╧═════════════╝

HL_B
╔════╤═════════╗
║ ID │ ValueID ║
╠════╪═════════╣
║ 1  │ 1       ║
╟────┼─────────╢
║ 1  │ 2       ║
╟────┼─────────╢
║ 1  │ 3       ║
╚════╧═════════╝

HL_C
╔════╤═════════╗
║ ID │ Product ║
╠════╪═════════╣
║ 1  │ A       ║
╟────┼─────────╢
║ 2  │ B       ║
╟────┼─────────╢
║ 3  │ C       ║
╚════╧═════════╝
```

I would like to update `HL_A.ProductType` to be a concatenation of `HL_C.Product` column. Like below:

```
╔════╤═════════════╗
║ ID │ ProductType ║
╠════╪═════════════╣
║ 1  │ A, B, C     ║
╚════╧═════════════╝
```

But my query only produces one value:

```
Update a
SET a.ProductType = STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + CAST(c.Producte AS VARCHAR(255))
        FROM HL_C c
        WHERE c.ID = b.ValueId
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,2,'')
FROM HL_A a
JOIN HL_B b
     ON a.ID = b.ID;
```

Output:

```
╔════╤═════════════╗
║ ID │ ProductType ║
╠════╪═════════════╣
║ 1  │ A           ║
╚════╧═════════════╝
```

Environment is SQL Server 2012. Can you please help?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Storing multiple, comma separated values is a bad design, and violates first normal form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for others to answer but none of them are working. In the end I achieved my goal like this:

```
Update a
SET a.ProductType = STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + CAST(c.Product AS VARCHAR(255))
        FROM HL_C c
        WHERE c.ID IN (SELECT ValueID FROM HL_B WHERE ID = b.ID)
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,2,'')
FROM HL_A a
JOIN HL_B b
     ON a.ID = b.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this - You should also check your design ???

**SOLUTION**

```
UPDATE a
SET a.ProductType = k.Pr
FROM 
HL_A a
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT u.ID , MAX(Pr) Pr
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT a.ID,STUFF((
                SELECT ', ' + CAST(c.Product AS VARCHAR(255))
                FROM HL_C c
                WHERE c.ID = b.ValueId
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                ,1,2,'') Pr
        FROM HL_A a
        JOIN HL_B b
             ON a.ID = b.ID
    )u GROUP BY u.ID 
)k ON k.ID = a.ID

SELECT * FROM HL_A
GO
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ID          ProductType
----------- -----------
1           A, B, C

(1 row affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

The update could be achieved by the below snippet -

```
declare @a table(id int,producttype varchar(10))
declare @b table(id int,valueid int)
declare @c table(id int,product varchar(10))
insert into @a values(1,'')
insert into @b values(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)
insert into @c values(1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C')

Update a
SET a.ProductType =
STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + CAST(c.product AS VARCHAR(255))
        FROM @c c inner join
        @b b on c.ID = b.ValueId
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,2,'')
from @a a 
inner join @b b1
on a.id = b1.id

select * from @a
```